# How to include a report in a VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, reporting

I have to include a Pie Chart Report in a visual Force page. I tried to use with a iFrame tag. But seems like its working .

`<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:iframe src="/01Z5B0000004w7B"/>

</apex:page>`

Please let me know , how to proceed further on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [**analytics:reportChart**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm) instead.

```
<apex:page> 
  <analytics:reportChart reportId="01Z5B0000004w7B" >
  </analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

> **analytics:reportChart**
>
> Use this component to add Salesforce report charts to a Visualforce
>   page. You can filter chart data to show specific results. The
>   component is available in API version 29.0 or later.
>
> Before you add a report chart, check that the source report has a
>   chart in Salesforce app.

Comment: Hi Shailesh, Thanks for the reply. One query. I am getting the report with the footer text  like  " As of Today at 1:​33 AM
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: " . How to get rid off this. I am not getting an attribute for this. Please let me know. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @ReshmiSmiju - I am not completely sure if this is related to your report. If you can elaborate or update the question with your code, I would be able to help on this.